# Detect Change in Cocos2D scene from App Delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

How do I detect a change in scene from the App Delegate?
I have a main menu that has a single button linking to a second page using cocos2D's menu system.

When the user presses the button, I transition scenes from MenuScene to GameScene.

Is it possible to detect this transition from the app delegate so that I can run some code when the scene transitions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use notifications to notify that the scene has transitioned. Somewhere in your appdelegate, listen for the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doSomethingAfterTransition) name:@"sceneTransitioned" object:nil];
```

In your GameScene's onEnterTransitionDidFinish method, you could post this notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"sceneTransitioned" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be in posting a notification everytime you change the scene.

The app delegate should be registered for that notification and receive the notification everytime the scene is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the callbacks already built-in the CCNode object (CCScene descends from CCNode) ... the below copy-paste from CCNode is from version 2.0, but i believe the methods date far back. Any coco 'onSomething' method, if you override it, dont forget to [super onSomething], otherwise your mileage will vary :)

```
/** Event that is called when the CCNode enters in the 'stage'.
 If the CCNode enters the 'stage' with a transition, this event is called when the transition finishes.
 If you override onEnterTransitionDidFinish, you shall 
 call [super onEnterTransitionDidFinish].
*/

-(void) onEnterTransitionDidFinish;


/** callback that is called every time the CCNode leaves the 'stage'.
 If the CCNode leaves the 'stage' with a transition, this callback is called 
 when the transition starts.
 */
-(void) onExitTransitionDidStart;
```